# Linux Mint 15 Olivia source list

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I am facing a problem downloading anything using apt-get tool. I have played with my source list and I think something went wrong. Synaptic also doesn't work.

I've searched for the original source list online and I found this:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ olivia main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring partner

# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu raring-getdeb apps
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu raring-getdeb games
```

So I have changed my /etc/apt/source.list

and typed `sudo apt-get update`
This is the output of the update

```
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                               
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg                     
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com raring Release.gpg [933 B]                  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg                       
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release                                   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release                           
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg [316 B]                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex             
Get:3 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia Release.gpg [198 B]                 
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg [316 B]                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex       
Get:5 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia Release [18.5 kB]                   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release                         
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Get:6 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/main amd64 Packages [23.5 kB]       
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring Release                                
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring Release                                
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex         
Get:7 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/upstream amd64 Packages [9,249 B]   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner amd64 Packages/DiffIndex       
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner i386 Packages/DiffIndex        
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex              
Get:8 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/import amd64 Packages [39.2 kB]     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner amd64 Packages                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources/DiffIndex                     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner i386 Packages                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex              
Get:9 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/main i386 Packages [23.5 kB]        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources/DiffIndex                     
Get:10 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/upstream i386 Packages [9,237 B]   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex               
Get:11 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/import i386 Packages [40.1 kB]     
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en_US              
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en                 
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources                               
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en               
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/import Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/import Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/main Translation-en_US
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/main Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/upstream Translation-en_US   
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/upstream Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Fetched 165 kB in 35s (4,642 B/s)
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D45DF2E8FC91AE7E
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4DF9B28CA252A784
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've tried to upgrade after that, I've got this with many other lines:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
```

For `sudo apt-get check` , this is the output

```
Reading package lists... Error!
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.linuxmint.com/ olivia/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.linuxmint.com_dists_olivia_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.linuxmint.com/ olivia/upstream amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.linuxmint.com_dists_olivia_upstream_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.linuxmint.com/ olivia/import amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.linuxmint.com_dists_olivia_import_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.linuxmint.com/ olivia/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.linuxmint.com_dists_olivia_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.linuxmint.com/ olivia/upstream i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.linuxmint.com_dists_olivia_upstream_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.linuxmint.com/ olivia/import i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.linuxmint.com_dists_olivia_import_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/universe i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-updates_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/universe amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/universe i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

This is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}`

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ olivia main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring partner

# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu raring-getdeb apps
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu raring-getdeb games


deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu raring main
#deb file:///usr/share/local-repository binary/

# Do not edit this file manually, use Software Sources instead.

deb http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia main upstream import  #id:linuxmint_main

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring partner
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu raring main
```

Any idea how can this be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bundle of problems, so let's start with the most important:

- Your version of Mint is obsolete. There are some improvements in newer versions of apt, found in recent version of Linux Mint that prevent problems like this:

  ```
    E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
    E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_main_i18n_Translation-en
    E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
  ```
- There are duplicated entries in your `sources.list` files. Search them and remove them. I'm seeing two "http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security" entries.
- Since you are using an obsolete version of Mint, and Mint use Ubuntu repositories mostly, you get several "Not Found" errors since they where removed from the servers to other servers. Update or change all the "security.ubuntu.com" and "archive.ubuntu.com" lines to "old-releases.ubuntu.com".
- There are three GPG errors, one BADSIG that is caused due Canonical's revocation of key, and two no available signatures since you didn't add them. Fix that also.
- Your package list cache is a mess. I would remove it entirely with:

  ```
    sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  ```

And then update the package list. This should be done after you have fixed all the previous issues, otherwise is likely that its effect will be negligible, but it should fix the `Reading package lists... Error!` message.

Remember, most of these issues are just blown away if you reinstall (since Linux Mint doesn't offer a reliable upgrade path) your OS anew with a recent version of Mint.